# How to force startSpan in with opentelemetry parentbased_always_off sampler

Tags: java, open-telemetry

I am trying to set up open telemetry with a sampler  (`-Dotel.traces.sampler=parentbased_always_off`).
And it works:

```
Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("span").startSpan()
```

No samples recorded.

Now I try to start sample manually so traces will be recorded only in some programmatically decided cases. And the issue is that I cannot find a method in api that allows me to do so. `startSpan` call is always ignored.

How can I force start trace recording?

In other words: how can I programmatically decide which span will records and which doesn't? For example I want record traces only for some specific users, not all.

Comment: Your description wasn't fully clear, do you want to customise the sampling behaviour to suit your use cases programatically?

Comment: Yes, I want to manually decide which span will record and which doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are looking for a way to customise sampling behaviour to decide upon whether or not span is recorded. Opentelemetry enables you to extend this by implementing your own `Sampler`.

Let's say you do not want to record any span with name *overflow* and rest are sampled. Your implementation would look something like this.

```java
package io.opentelemetry.sdk.extension.trace.mycustom.sampler;

...
import io.opentelemetry.api.common.Attributes;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.SpanKind;
import io.opentelemetry.context.Context;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.data.LinkData;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.samplers.Sampler;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.samplers.SamplingResult;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.sampler.SamplingDecision;
...


public final class MyCustomSampler implements Sampler {

  ...
    
  @Override
  public SamplingResult shouldSample(
      Context parentContext,
      String traceId,
      String name,
      SpanKind spanKind,
      Attributes attributes,
      List<LinkData> parentLinks) {
    // your logic goes here
    return name == "overflow" ? SamplingResult.drop() : SamplingResult.recordAndSample();
  }

  @Override
  public String getDescription() {
    return "MyCustomSampler";
  }

}
```

You can take a look at the default samplers [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk/trace/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/sdk/trace/samplers) or one of the sdk-extension [jaeger-remote-sampler](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/jaeger-remote-sampler) to get better idea.

Comment: But is it possible to set custom sampler for opentelemetry java agent?

Comment: This guide helps you to do that https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation#creating-agent-extensions